# check childId match with parentId or not in js

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures, logic

Here I have created a function that will compile whether an object's parentid matches its childId or not, so id 1 is a parent Id that has a child with 11,12, so if I call that function checkParentId(obj, 1, 12), that will return true, but here I have gotten the result false in the rest of the console statements, so how do I make the changes in that programme so that I will get the desired result? The program is given below.

```
const obj = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "parent 1",
          children: [
            {
              id: 11,
              name: "child 1",
              children: [
                {
                  id: 12,
                  name: "grand 1",
                  children: []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "parent 2",
          children: [
            {
              id: 21,
              name: "c1",
              children: []
            }
          ]
        },
      ];
      const checkParentId = (obj, parentId, childId) => {
    for (let item of obj) {
      if (item.id === parentId) {
        return true;
      }
      if (item.children.length > 0) {
        return checkParentId(item.children, parentId, childId);
      }
      return false;
    }
  };
      console.log(checkParentId(obj, 1, 12)); // true
      console.log(checkParentId(obj, 1, 21)); // false
      console.log(checkParentId(obj, 1, 11)); // true
      console.log(checkParentId(obj, 2, 21)); // true
      console.log(checkParentId(obj, 1, 2)); // false
```

Comment: `return` within a foreach doesn’t do anything useful

Comment: So what should I change instead of that?

Comment: Try using a for loop instead of foreach…`for (let item of obj)`

Comment: Why is for each not working and for is working?

Comment: Because forEach takes a function as its parameter, and your `return`s are within that.

Comment: what about 11,21

Comment: after changing for also I am getting true,true,false,true  but it should be true,false,true,false

Comment: You didn’t use `childId` in your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Currently, you are *always* searching the whole `obj`

You want to search only within a particular entry inside `obj`. Therefore I think you need two functions.

One function will find an person inside an *array* of people.

The other function is your actual parent-child tester: it *first* finds the parent, and then looks within for the child.

### Calling an array `obj` is asking for trouble

It makes it hard to keep track of what is a list of items, and what is an item.

```js
const parents = [ // This is an ARRAY, not an object
  {
    id: 1,
    children: [{
      id: 11,
      children: [{
        id: 12,
        children: [],
      }, ],
    }, ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    children: [{
      id: 21,
      children: [],
    }, ],
  },
];

function findPersonInArray(people, id) { // Make clear that you are expecting an ARRAY of people

  let found = null
  people.forEach(person => { 
    if (person.id === id) {
      found = person;
    }
    if (person.children && person.children.length > 0) {
      const child = findPersonInArray(person.children, id);
      if (child) {
        found = child;
      }
    }
  })
  return found // This was one line too early in your code, stopping JS from looking in Person 2
};

function checkParentId(parents, parentId, childId) {
  const parent = findPersonInArray(parents, parentId);
  if (parent) {
    if (childId === parentId) { // Special case if parent and child are same
      return true;
    }
    if (findPersonInArray(parent.children, childId)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(checkParentId(parents, 1, 12)); // true
console.log(checkParentId(parents, 1, 21)); // false
console.log(checkParentId(parents, 1, 11)); // true
console.log(checkParentId(parents, 2, 21)); // true
console.log(checkParentId(parents, 1, 2)); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when your code finds the parent node, it *returns*, but it should actually perform recursive searches below *that* node to find the child node.

As you need to search for *two* nodes, it will be useful to first define a function that finds *one* node given an array of nodes to search into. Then you can use that function to first find the parent in the whole hierarchy, and then  -- when you have found the parent node -- do a second search among the children of that found parent to find the child node. If all that succeeds, you can return `true`.

Here is the code for that:

```js
const findNode = (nodes, id) => {
    for (const node of nodes) {
        const match = node.id === id ? node : findNode(node.children, id);
        if (match) return match;
    }
};

const checkParentId = (nodes, parentId, childId) => {
    const parent = findNode(nodes, parentId);
    return !!(parent && findNode(parent.children, childId));
};

// Your example & tests
const obj = [{id: 1,name: "parent 1",children: [{id: 11,name: "child 1",children: [{id: 12,name: "grand 1",children: []}]}]},{id: 2,name: "parent 2",children: [{id: 21,name: "c1",children: []}]},];
      
console.log(checkParentId(obj, 1, 12)); // true
console.log(checkParentId(obj, 1, 21)); // false
console.log(checkParentId(obj, 1, 11)); // true
console.log(checkParentId(obj, 2, 21)); // true
console.log(checkParentId(obj, 1, 2)); // false
```